# Como retornar apenas uma coluna

Tags: doctrine-2

Pessoal tenho a seguinte query feita.

```
$ent->createQueryBuilder('t')
                ->select('count(t.id)')
                ->join('t.categoria', 'c')
                ->join('t.noticia', 'n')
                ->groupBy('n.id')
                ->where('n.posicao=1')
                ->andWhere('c.id=16')
                ->andWhere(' t.deleted_at IS NULL OR LENGTH(t.deleted_at) = 0')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

So que ela não esta me retornando apenas uma coluna com o count. Acredito que seja por causa do groupBy. Como eu acerto ela para retornar apenas o total do count sem tirar o groupBy. 
Obrigado

Comment: O que a query está retornando?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Retorna um erro dizendo que esta sendo retornado varias colunas.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti esta é a mensagem de erro retornada: `The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal eu consegui resolver usando o Distinct. Ficou assim:

```
$ent->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('count(DISTINCT c.id)')
            ->join('t.categoria', 'c')
            ->join('t.noticia', 'n')
            ->where('n.posicao=1')
            ->andWhere('c.id=16')
            ->andWhere(' t.deleted_at IS NULL OR LENGTH(t.deleted_at) = 0')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

A query gerada pelo `QueryBuilder` está errada, já que está retornando não apenas o resultado do `COUNT(t.id)`, mas também todas as colunas de `t`.

Troque o código acima por:

```
$ent->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('count(t.id)')
     ->join('t.categoria', 'c')
     ->join('t.noticia', 'n')
     ->groupBy('n.id')
     ->where('n.posicao=1')
     ->andWhere('c.id=16')
     ->andWhere(' t.deleted_at IS NULL OR LENGTH(t.deleted_at) = 0')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getSingleScalarResult();
```